# How to use a parent classmethod that returns an instance in an overriding child method?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a parent `classmethod` that returns an instance of the class. Later I have a child class in which I would like to use the `classmethod` of the parent and return an instance of the child class. I am using python 3.9

An example could be the following:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, s):
        print("init in class A")
        self.s = s
    
    @classmethod
    def f(cls, s):
        print("f in class A")
        return cls(s)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, s):
        print("init in class B")
        super().__init__(s)

    @classmethod
    def f(cls, s):
        print("f in class B")
        a = A.f(s)
        # a = super(B, cls).f(s)
        # a = super().f(s)
        s = "class B " + a.s
        return cls(s)
```

Looking at the output, written like this it seems to work.

```
>>> B.f("toto").s 
f in class B
f in class A
init in class A
init in class B
init in class A

'class B toto'
```

But if I uncomment one of the two commented lines in the `classmethod` f in class B (for example `super(B, cls).f(s)`), I got this:

```
>>> B.f("toto").s 
f in class B
f in class A
init in class B
init in class A
init in class B
init in class A

'class B toto'
```

The result is the same but I do not understand why from the `classmethod` of class  A, it goes first from the `__init__` method of class B?

I get the feeling that in the `classmetod` of A, `cls` is still class B. But I don't know how to change this.

Comment: The point of using a `classmethod` is to handle the case if it is called for a subclass to have access to the particular class (e. g.. for object creation like here). Otherwise you could just use a `staticmethod` instead.

Comment: Indeed: while the *attribute lookup* on the `super` object finds `A.f`, it's still `cls == B` that's used in the subsequent call. That is, `super().f(s)` is equivalent to `A.__dict__['f'](B, s)`.

Comment: You can see what `super` uses if do something like `sup = super(); print(sup.__self__, sup.__self_class__)` before `a = sup.f(s)`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you, from your print you can clearly see that B is effectively used in the A classmethod if I use `super()`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Using a `staticmehtod`, is the way to implement the same or there is another option? I mean, I must again have to use `A.f(s)`. If I try with `super()` I fall in the same issue.

Comment: In `A.f` you can just write `return A(s)` to always create an `A` object. `A.f` can then be a classmethod with an unused parameter `cls` or a staticmethod.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you, I did it like this.